# scala - scalatest - eventually trait wins over fail assertion?

Tags: scala, scalatest, assertion

by documentation,
[eventually trait](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.1-2.12/org/scalatest/concurrent/Eventually$.html)

> Invokes the passed by-name parameter repeatedly until it either
>   succeeds, or a configured maximum amount of time has passed, sleeping
>   a configured interval between attempts.

but [fail](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_assertions),

> fail to fail a test unconditionally;

so i want to use eventually in order to wait until a successful status arrived, but use fail to fail the test if i already know that the test must to fail

e.g.

converting a video with ffmpeg i will wait until conversion is not completed but if conversion reach "error" status i want to make the test fail

with this test

```
  test("eventually fail") {
    eventually (timeout(Span(30, Seconds)), interval(Span(15, Seconds))) {
      println("Waiting... ")
      assert(1==1)
      fail("anyway you must fail")
    }
  }
```

i understand that i cannot make a test "fail unconditionally" inside eventually cicle : it looks like eventually will ignore  "fail" until timeout.

[image]

is this a correct behaviour?

Comment: fail throw an exception, which is caught in eventually so you are not failing the test,  but just one eventually try.

Comment: so, in the assertion scalatest documentation, fail should not "fail test unconditionally" but it "throw exception"?

Comment: The test still fails unconditionally (i.e., in any situation), after `eventually` completes.
It doesn't say that it fails it _immediately_, does it? :)

Comment: I agree with both of you ;).
You should write your own eventually which would fail fast on `fail()` and continue trying on `continue()`. If your implementation satisfy you and if you think this usage is generalised you could also propose it as scalatest PR. :)

Answer (score 1):

> so, in the assertion scalatest documentation, fail should not "fail test unconditionally" but it "throw exception"?

It's the same because the only way to fail a test in Scalatest is to throw an exception.

Look at [the source](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/blob/release-3.0.6/scalatest/src/main/scala/org/scalatest/concurrent/Eventually.scala#L391-L401):

```
def eventually[T](fun: => T)(implicit config: PatienceConfig): T = {
  val startNanos = System.nanoTime
  def makeAValiantAttempt(): Either[Throwable, T] = {
    try {
      Right(fun)
    }
    catch {
      case tpe: TestPendingException => throw tpe
      case e: Throwable if !anExceptionThatShouldCauseAnAbort(e) => Left(e)
    }
  }
  ...
```

So if you want to get your failure through, you could use [`pending`](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.1-2.12/org/scalatest/Assertions.html#pending:org.scalatest.Assertionwithorg.scalatest.PendingStatement) instead of `fail` (but of course, the test will be reported as pending, not failed). Or write your own version of `eventually` which lets more exceptions through.